# Docker can't find local Node modules?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a Node express app that I'm trying to turn into a Docker image and run in a container. The problem I'm having is that it seems in the containerized version of my app, it can't find my local modules `av-request` and `aml-request`, but it has no issue finding the installed modules.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var av = require('./modules/av-request')
var aml = require('./modules/aml-request')

var app = express();
...
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM node:carbon
# Create container's working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
COPY ./app/package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install
# Bundle app source
COPY ./app/* /usr/src/app/
# Verify directory contents 
RUN ls /usr/src/app/
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is my output from the build and run process. Notice that in step 7 when we run `ls /usr/src/app/` it shows all the files that were copied over but not any directory structure or anything. Based on how `ls` normally works I would expect it to list directories as well but none are shown. **This gives me the impression that all my files from my application exist at the root directory level for some reason.** Am I copying my application correctly? The correct file structure is below, but I don't see anything at all like this in the output from my build process.

```
- app/
    - package.json
    - app.js
    - modules/
    - node_modules/
    - private/
    - public/
    - views/
- dockerfile
- .dockerignore
```

And this is the output when I build the image.

```
docker build -t webapp .
Step 1/9 : FROM node:carbon
...
Step 7/9 : RUN ls /usr/src/app/
 ---> Running in 9951fa3289da
accepts
acorn
acorn-globals
ajv
align-text
amdefine
aml-request.js
app.js
array-flatten
...
Successfully built f3d877bc94da
Successfully tagged webapp:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have
'-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

I can verify the image exists when I run `docker images`

Then I run `docker run -d -p 8080:80 webapp` which spits out the container ID. Now when I run `docker ps -l` it shows the container status as `Exited (1)` so I go check out the logs.

```
docker logs b3fcc5a6f545

> app@0.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node app.js

module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './modules/av-request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/app.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app@0.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the app@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: just a hunch: in your dockerfile, try and change `# Bundle app source
COPY ./app/* /usr/src/app/` to `# Bundle app source
COPY ./app /usr/src/app`. Also to check your filesystem inside the docker container you can also just run `docker exec -it webapp /bin/bash` to connect to the container and just use `ls -al` to see what's going on.

Comment: This was the solution, found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215830/dockerfile-copy-keep-subdirectory-structure and realized. My intuition still feels like the * shouldn't ruin the directory structure but it was an easy fix regardless.