# Docker container throwing error on running it

Tags: node.js, docker

I have been learning docker for now, i made a docker file which is like this.

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json /app/

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
ADD ./* /app/

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

And my file directory looks like this,

[image]

My server is working fine with my local machine, however, when running with docker container it's throwing an error.
The error is:
[image]

Can someone help me with it ?

Comment: Why are you using ADD for bundling you app and not COPY: `COPY . /app/ ` and how are you building your image , normally  the syntax forbuilding an image is `$ docker build -t <your username>/<your-web-app> .`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `Dockerfile` to the following and try:

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app/

# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nano

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

# RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

CMD ["node", "server.js"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

When you set `WORKDIR to /app/`, the current directory is updated. So there no need to mention `/app` during copy.

Answer (score 1):

`ADD ./* /app/` does not what you probably think it does. It matches all files that satisfy `./*` according to Go's filepath match [(docs)](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match) and copies them to `/app/`. For details, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215830/dockerfile-copy-keep-subdirectory-structure) answer.

What you should do instead is `add . /app/` or `add . .` (which are equivalent, because you changed the workdir to `/app`). That recurisvely copies the contents of your current directory into the container fileysystem, maintaining the directory structure.