# Docker build can't find EntityFramework.props

Tags: .net, docker, entity-framework, nuget, dockerfile

I'm building a .NET Framework 4.8 class library in a Docker file.
The class library is referencing Entity Framework 6.4.4.
My solution builds ok in Visual Studio 2019 on my laptop.

The Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8

WORKDIR C:\src\lib\MyClassLib
COPY src\lib\MyClassLib\ .
RUN nuget restore packages.config -PackagesDirectory ..\..\packages
RUN msbuild MyClassLib.csproj
```

The NuGet restore step seems to go well:

```
Added package 'EntityFramework.6.4.4' to folder 'C:\packages'
```

But in the next step that does the build, the EntityFramework reference could not be found.

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props.
```

Based on the folder structure, the relative path to the packages folder in .csproj should end up in C:\packages.
The file that it is complaining about, is actually present. I inspected it using
RUN dir C:\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build in the Docker file.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the error may come from the definition of your directories.

The WORKDIR command refers to the working directory in the container you are creating, not a path in your original file system ([reference](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-workdir-command-in-docker)), so, when you define `WORKDIR C:\src\lib\MyClassLib`, you are actually creating that directory in the container, not pointing to your file system. (I have other details on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65634892/docker-configuration-does-not-find-existing-file/65635136))

Maybe you want to do something like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8

WORKDIR "/src/lib/MyClassLib" # workdir that receives the copy below
COPY src\lib\MyClassLib\ .

WORKDIR "/packages" # workdir to receive the packages
COPY packages . # copy into the workdir
RUN nuget restore packages.config

WORKDIR "/src/lib/MyClassLib" # workdir that contains your csproj - I don't know if it is actually here
RUN msbuild MyClassLib.csproj
```

[EDIT] I don't know if you intend to copy folders' content recursively or not. Either way, you may find information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215830/dockerfile-copy-keep-subdirectory-structure)

I am sorry if this snippet is not actually accurate, but it is more of a "way to go" with the information I got, than a final solution. Hope it helps though :)

Comment: I was already aware that C:\src was pointing to the file system of the container image, not to my local path. However, your suggestion actually worked! All I did was change the WORKDIR lines to relative paths rather than C:\src. But I don't understand why yet. Does this make sense?

Comment: Glad it helped :) In Docker, the relative paths may actually be defined without the slash, as show in this definition https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir