# Docker configuration does not find existing file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, rider, run-configuration

I try to configure and run a docker file in IntelliJ Rider.

During the build, I get the following error:

```
Step 7/17 : COPY ["src/No.Services/No.Gf/No.Gf.Api/No.Gf.Api.csproj", 
"src/No.Services/No.Gf/No.Gf.Api/"]
Error response from daemon: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: 
stat src\No.Services\No.Gf\No.Gf.Api\No.Gf.Api.csproj: file does not exist
```

The file is right where the path points to. It's not exluded in .dockerignore.

I am out of options here?

Step 6 is:

```
Step 6/17 : WORKDIR /src
```

Maybe this is adding one "/src" to much and in step 7 it's finally looking for the file in /src/src/...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your physical directory hierarchies, but I would say that the reason of the error may be the original relative path between the `Dockerfile` and the `csproj`. With the `csproj` location stated like `src/No.Services/No.Gf/...`, the `Dockerfile` will have to be at the same level of that `src` folder, for the copy to be successful.

Could you please verify this?

(If you are working with a typical `dotnet` solution on top of the project, setting the `Dockerfile` in the root of the solution may solve your error, since it will respect the folders' hierarchy.)

Regarding the other topics:

- The `WORKDIR` command refers to the working directory in the container ([reference](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-the-workdir-command-in-docker)), so, I would say that it is not the reason for your error, because it seems that, when copying, the file is not found in its source.
- When the copy into the container is successful, it will probably be in a directory like `src/src/No.Services/No.Gf/...`, but this is after copying, inside the container.

Comment: Thank you, that's it. I misinterpreted the context folder setting. Just set it to ".".